# RxJava: retrying map actions

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have an Observable where each item is transformed in a way that may result in an exception, but can be retried. I don't want failures to break the stream, as each item represents an independent transaction. The best solution I can come up with is this:

```
    final AtomicLong errCount = new AtomicLong();
    Observable.from(ImmutableList.of(1L, 2L, 3L)).flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Long>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Long> call(Long aLong) {
            return Observable.from(ImmutableList.of(aLong)).map(new Func1<Long, Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long call(Long aLong) {
                    if (aLong == 2 && errCount.getAndIncrement() < 1) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("retryable error");
                    }
                    return aLong * 100;
                }
            }).retry(2);
        }
    }).forEach(new Action1<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Long aLong) {
            System.out.println(aLong);
        }
    });

// Desired output: 100, 200, 300 (not 100, 100, 200, 300)
```

Problems:

- The retry logic is really verbose.
- If any item fails after 2 retries, the stream is broken (no more items are processed). I'd like a clean way to return both exceptions and results like Finagle's Try, so I can process all the exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The retry logic is really verbose.

You can avoid using the `ImmutableList` entirely by switching to the `Observable.just(t1, t2, t3)` constructor. This essentially does the same thing but less verbose.

I see that you are flatMapping in order to convert each value to an Observable. This would prevent an onError encountered while mapping a single value from unsubscribing the entire chain. So when an operator throws it will unsubscribe from just that one value's inner observable chain. Otherwise an error would cause an unsubscribe and resubscribe from the main outer observable.

I can think of 2 choices if you want to maintain this behavior but reduce the boiler plate (aside from the obvious switch to Java8 lambdas).

Firstly, **resubscribe and dedupe** your data after the post-retry. If you have a value that has a good `hashcode` and `equals` implementation you could use a filter to append to a stateful set and onNext only when the set does not already contain the value.

```java
Observable.<Long> just(1L, 2L, 3L)
        .map(new Func1<Long, Long>() {
            @Override
            public Long call(Long aLong) {
                if (aLong == 2 && errCount.getAndIncrement() < 1) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("retryable error");
                }
                return aLong * 100;
            }})
        .retry(2)
        .filter(new Func1<Long, Boolean>() {
            Set<Long> state = null;

            @Override
            public Boolean call(Long a) {
                if (state == null)
                    state = new HashSet<Long>();
                if (!state.contains(a)) {
                    state.add(a);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }})
        .forEach(new Action1<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Long aLong) {
                System.out.println(aLong);
            }});
```

Secondly, you could switch your observable to **resume** from where it left off when resubscribed to. Note that this can have problems with data loss when using operators that buffer (observeOn, merge, flatMap). That is because they will continue to consume from the producer in a manner decoupled from the downstream consumer. So you would want to make sure that you do not buffer before your retry. Also there are other considerations if you are implementing an observable source that supports back-pressure.

```java
// Should resume right where it left off
resumableObservable.map(...).retry(2).observeOn()

// Don't do this. ObserveOn will buffer values and resume will lose data.
resumableObservable.map(...).observeOn().retry(2)

// Also bad if running async observables. Merging buffers so this could have data loss.
Observable.merge(resumableObservable.map(...)).retry(2)
```

> If any item fails after 2 retries, the stream is broken (no more items are processed). I'd like a clean way to return both exceptions and results like Finagle's Try, so I can process all the exceptions.

You could change the unreliable map from a `Long -> Long` to a `Long -> Tuple<Long, List<Exception>>`. As this is quite a mouthful of generics and quickly becomes cumbersome I'd recommend using a different variant of the retry operator, namely `retryWhen(Func1<Observable<Throwable>, Observable<?>>)`. Here is an example of how to use it in your code.

```java
}).retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>>(){
@Override
public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> o) {
    final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
    return o.filter(new Func1<Throwable, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(Throwable t) {
            return t instanceof RuntimeException || count.getAndIncrement() < 5;
        }}).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.immediate());
}})
```

The benefit of using a retryWhen is that you can easily implement a delayed retry after some amount of time in a non-blocking style.